# JAX-RS & Jersey: Properly Nested JSON

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-rs

I am fairly new to using JAX-RS and Jersey. The problem I am facing is that I cannot get a response in JSON the way I would like. I want a response that is something similar to the following:

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "car": {
        "id": 42,
        "name": "toyota",
        "model": "camry"
    }
}
```

So far I have a class named Car. It has 3 fields: id, name, and model with getters and setters. I get properly formatted JSON response of a single instance of a Car using the function whose return type is Car.

```
public Car getCarWithId(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        return carService.getCarWithId(id);
    }
```

This only gives me the following:

```
{
    "id": 42,
    "name": "toyota",
    "model": "camry"
 }
```

How can I get the response with the "result":"success". This will help me solve more complex problems in the future. Thanks for any help.

P.S. I thought about trying to return a hashmap but that gives me an error and seems like I would go into a deeper hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're provider is Jackson, you could wrap it in a custom `ResponseEntity` object with a `result` field, along with a `Map<String, Object>` with the getter annotated with `@JsonAnyGetter`. For instance

```
public class ResponseEntity {

    private String result;
    private final Map<String, Object> otherFields = new HashMap<>();

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getOtherFields() {
        return otherFields;
    }

    public void addField(String field, Object value) {
        otherFields.put(field, value);
    }
}
```

What the `@JsonAnyGetter` does is make it so that the `otherField` is not serialized, but only the properties in the `Map`. You after you create the instance, and all `entity.addField("car", carObject);`, you will get your desired result.

Comment: I am using Jersey. I am looking for something similar to this, however if you could help me out for Jersey it would help a lot. I am looking into creating a response wrapper class as of now.

(Maybe I am using Jackson? How can I check - like I said very new to this (apologies)

Comment: Jersey is not a JSON provider. Jersey requires a JSON provider to handle JSON. You obviously have one but know it, because you can handle JSON. If you don't know what provider it is, it is most likely Jackson

Comment: @JsonAnyGetter is giving me an error asking me to Create annotation. Is there anything I can import? (I am assuming I have Jackson as well)

Comment: Can you update your post with your Jersey related dependencies, and let me know what server you are using.

Comment: I pulled the jersey maven dependency 
org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes 
jersey-quickstart-webapp
2.22.1
I will update it with the dependencies within this project. Currently on Tomcat 7

Comment: No need to update. Change the `jersey-media-moxy` in the pom to `jersey-media-json-jackson`. You should then be able to import `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter`

Comment: Yes, It worked like a charm. Thanks for dumbing it down for me!